# IdentityServer4 endpoint skip port address attached to the URL

Tags: c#, identityserver4

The Identityserver4 end point is not using the port address of the .well-known/openid-configuration URL http://example.org:7000/.well-known/openid-configuration

```
"issuer": "http://example.org:7000",
"jwks_uri": "http://example.org/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe": "http://example.org/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/revocation",
"introspection_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/introspect",
"device_authorization_endpoint": "http://example.org/connect/deviceauthorization"
```

How can i set the endpoints to attach the port address like this below

```
"issuer": "http://example.org:7000",
"jwks_uri": "http://example.org:7000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe": "http://example.org:7000/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/rev`enter code here`ocation"
"introspection_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/introspect",
"device_authorization_endpoint": "http://example.org:7000/connect/deviceauthorization"
```

Comment: I just opened the Quickstart project and what you're asking for seems to be the default. My project is running at https://localhost:5001 and the port 5001 is part of each of the URIs in my discovery endpoint output starts with https://localhost:5001.

Maybe check the options on the services.AddIdentityServer statement in ConfigureServices?

Also - I'm guessing you did a search and replace. In your "what I want" example, the issuer  URI has :7000 repeated.

Comment: its working fine on localhost but if i deploy to a remote server using www.xxx.com:7000. All the end point won't have the port address. the issuer with :7000 was a mistake while trying to compose the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the domain by ensuring the domain has no port address but port 80.